# How to setup the OCSP responder

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, ssl, openssl, ocsp

I have generated the certificates as given below:

```
Root-CA  ->  Intermediate-CA  ->  Server

Root-CA:
rootca.key
rootca.crt

Intermediate-CA:
intermediateca.key
intermediateca.crt

Server:
server.key
server.crt
```

My openssl.conf for Server:

```
[ server_cert ]
authorityInfoAccess = OCSP;URI:http://www.example.com

[ ocsp ]
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid,issuer
keyUsage = critical, digitalSignature
extendedKeyUsage = critical, OCSPSigning
```

My Nginx conf:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 SSL;
        server_name www.example.com;

        ssl_certificate  /home/user/conffiles/server+intermediateca.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /home/user/conffiles/server.key;

        ssl_ocsp on;
        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /home/user/conffiles/rootca+intermediateca.crt;
}
```

I am not getting any output with the following command:

```
echo QUIT | openssl s_client -connect www.example.com:443 -status 2> /dev/null | grep -A 17 'OCSP response:' | grep -B 17 'Next Update'
```

Using the following command:

```
openssl s_client -connect www.example.com:443 -tls1_2 -tlsextdebug -status
```

I get the below output:

```
OCSP response: no response sent
```

Anyone, can you please tell me how to setup the OCSP responder?

Please help me, I need this bug fixed. I appreciate your time. Thank you.

Comment: As you haven't said which vendor's OCSP responder you're planning to use, may I suggest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68835032/how-to-make-a-ocsp-responder just to get you testing?

Answer (score 1):

> How to setup the OCSP responder?

Wikipedia lists several OSCP responder implementations [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_Certificate_Status_Protocol#Implementations). Each server will have their own specific installation and configuration instructions.

For testing purposes the [`openssl ocsp`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/openssl-ocsp.html)  implementation  might be a useful light-weight solution.
The manual lists several usage examples including:

> OCSP server on port 8888 using a standard ca configuration, and a separate responder certificate. All requests and responses are printed to a file.
>
> ```
> openssl ocsp -index demoCA/index.txt -port 8888 -rsigner rcert.pem -CA demoCA/cacert.pem -text -out log.txt
> ```
>
> As above but exit after processing one request:
>
> ```
> openssl ocsp -index demoCA/index.txt -port 8888 -rsigner rcert.pem -CA demoCA/cacert.pem -nrequest 1
> ```